# assertRaises does not catch exception / does not complain about no exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

This code does not work as expected. I'm getting pass when expecting fail; and fail when expecting pass for assertRaises().

`test_db.py:`

```
import unittest

class TestConnectDatabase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_close(self):
        self.assertRaises(ReferenceError, self.close_database()) # <--- Problem #1
        pass

    # Just a stub for brevity...
    def close_database(self):
        #raise Exception(ReferenceError)                         # <--- Problem #2
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In this example the code passes the unit test even though the exception was not raised. If `#raise` is uncommented, the exception is just passed to command line and the test fails when it should pass.

Executing test using: 
`python -m test_db` or `python test_db.py`

Comment: @Mark, @DavidCullen: Making sure what's passed in is a reference seems to fix the issue of it not flagging the exception. However, if I uncomment `#raise Exception(ReferenceError)` the test still fails!? ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\test_db.py", line 5, in test_close
    self.assertRaises(ReferenceError, self.close_database)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\unittest\case.py", line 473, in assertRaises
    callableObj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\test_db.py", line 9, in close_database
    raise Exception(ReferenceError)
Exception: <type 'exceptions.ReferenceError'>```

Comment: Have you tried `raise ReferenceError("This is an error.")` instead of `raise Exception(ReferenceError)`? @kashiraja

Comment: __That does seems to work...awesome!__ I'm really in new territory here.. Thx for your help!

Comment: That's not a problem, happy to help!  :) @kashiraja

Comment: @alecxe This question should probably not be marked duplicate anylonger?

Comment: @kashiraja I still think is is a duplicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the method `self.close_database`, when you should just be passing a reference to it. Remove the parentheses e.g.

```
def test_close(self):
    self.assertRaises(ReferenceError, self.close_database)
```

Check out [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses after `self.close_database`:

```
class TestConnectDatabase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_close(self):
        self.assertRaises(ReferenceError, self.close_database)
        pass
```

You are calling `self.close_database` which means its result (`None`) gets passed to `assertRaises`. See the documentation for [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises]).